# in the WebSocketInterceptor method of springboot webSocket and return a value to the front-end if the verification fails

Tags: websocket

Before establishing the ws connection, first verify the token value. If the verification fails, I want to return friendly information to the front-end, but now the front-end cannot obtain this friendly information. My interception code is as follows:

public class WebSocketInterceptor implements HandshakeInterceptor {

```
@Override
public boolean beforeHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response, WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Map<String, Object> attributes) throws Exception {
    // 在这里进行 Token 校验逻辑
    String token = extractToken((ServletServerHttpRequest) request);
    if (!validateToken(token)) {
        // 校验不通过，返回友好提示信息给前端
        response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        response.getBody().write("Token authentication failed".getBytes());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void afterHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response, WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Exception exception) {
    // 暂时不需要处理
}

private String extractToken(ServletServerHttpRequest request) {
    // 从请求头或参数中提取 Token，根据实际情况进行处理
    return request.getServletRequest().getParameter("token");
}

private boolean validateToken(String token) {
    // 编写你的 Token 校验逻辑
    // 返回 true 表示校验通过，返回 false 表示校验不通过
    return false;
}
```

my code follow:
public class WebSocketInterceptor implements HandshakeInterceptor {

```
@Override
public boolean beforeHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response, WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Map<String, Object> attributes) throws Exception {
    // 在这里进行 Token 校验逻辑
    String token = extractToken((ServletServerHttpRequest) request);
    if (!validateToken(token)) {
        // 校验不通过，返回友好提示信息给前端
        response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        response.getBody().write("Token authentication failed".getBytes());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void afterHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response, WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Exception exception) {
    // 暂时不需要处理
}

private String extractToken(ServletServerHttpRequest request) {
    // 从请求头或参数中提取 Token，根据实际情况进行处理
    return request.getServletRequest().getParameter("token");
}

private boolean validateToken(String token) {
    return false;
}
```